# Unable To see My .ts files inside sources in Developer tools in my Angular 12 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After a recent angular 12 upgrade I am unable to see my .ts files inside sources in Dev tool. The web pack bundler doesn't seems to be loaded. sourceMap in angular.json is true still the files are not loading. Anyone please let me know what all things I need to check here. This is an inconvenience as I generally debug through the browser.Below is the content of my angular Json file.

```
       {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "load-board": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "ntg-load-board",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/out",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.single-spa.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@ntgfreight/ui-components/style/style.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
              "libraryName": "load-board",
              "libraryTarget": "umd"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "stg": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stg.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "load-board:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "load-board:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
                "browserTarget": "load-board:build:dev"
             }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "load-board:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@ntgfreight/ui-components/style/style.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "load-board:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "load-board:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "load-board",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to to update your serve section to include the development `browserTarget` to dev configuration:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "load-board:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "load-board:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "load-board:build:dev"
           }
          }
        },
```

And run your project using:

```
ng serve load-board --configuration development
```

Read more about Angular12: https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49

Comment: This doesn't help. I have edited my question with my updated angular json file.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: I realize that typo as soon as I posted my last comment. However the issue is still not resolved. Please see my updated Angular.json In the edited question. BTW I am really thankful for you help so far,  will be grateful If we can resolve this as it is difficult to debug currently.

Comment: You need to run the project in development mode as in Angular 12, it by defaults runs the production configuration. Check updated answer.

Comment: Below are the scripts that I am using to host my app. But it doesn't seem to work.

"build:local": "ng build load-board --configuration development",
 "start:local": "ng s --project load-board --proxy-config proxy-dev.config.json --disable-host-check --port 4206 --live-reload false",

Comment: Are you using npm run start:local command?

Comment: Yes, and my project is running in development Mode. Can you Please check if there is anything in dev configuration that needs to be changed as part of Angular 12 upgrade? As far as I know SourceMap should be true for files mapping and its already true.

Answer (score 2):

With the following add-on to my `Angular.json`, section `"configurations"`:

```
"development": {
    "buildOptimizer": false,
    "optimization": false,
    "vendorChunk": true,
    "extractLicenses": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "namedChunks": true
},
```

and using explicit `--configuration development"` or just supplying `"defaultConfiguration": "development"` in `"build"` and `"serve"` sections I can see `.ts` files in my DevTools. Make sure you are looking in right path of DevTools: `webpack://./src/app/`.